# Turn off `PLAY` header in `ansible-playbook`, to make it even less verbose

Tags: ansible

I am using ansible (v2.9.9 on Ubuntu Linux 18.04) to manage many different servers doing many different things, and I want to reduce the amount of output that gets printed when I run it. I have many playbooks & plays (40+ plays)

I have `stdout_callback = actionable` in `ansible.cfg` (in `[defaults]` section) so tasks which don't change don't get printed to the console when running `ansible-playbook`. *However* ansible still prints the `PLAY [$GROUP]` line (& a newline) when starting a play, and if no host is matched it'll print `skipping: no hosts matched`. e.g.:

```
PLAY [all] *************************

PLAY [all] *************************

PLAY [webservers] ******************

PLAY [apache_webservers] ***********

PLAY [https_webservers] ************
skipping: no hosts matched

PLAY [databases] *******************
```

Can I turn this off? Can I make ansible be really, really quiet? If a task in a play is change (& hence to be printed), then print the `PLAY [$GROUP] ***` line, but otherwise, I don't want that header to be printed? Ideally, I want it like traditional unix CLI tools. If nothing changes, print nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Should the options of a plugin not meet your needs, select a different plugin, or write your own.

Requirement of only changed tasks may not be met by callbacks released with Ansible. [unixy](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback/unixy.html) and [dense](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback/dense.html) are less verbose options, but print play start, and play summary.

At the other extreme is [null](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback/null.html), but that doesn't print anything.

Also: actionable is effectively default with `display_skipped_hosts = no` and `display_ok_hosts = no`.  actionable will eventually be removed.